# Connect a button of a table view cell to the corresponding ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a class `MyCell.h` / `MyCell.m` which is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. In this class I only have four IBOutlet properties, three labels and one button.

In the implementation I only have synthesize'd these properties.

Then I have a `MyCell.xib` which is an `UITableViewCell` and I connected the elements to the MyCell class properties.

In a `MyViewController` I put an `UITableView` in it and the table view cells are styled with the one of `MyCell.xib`, also they are conntect, the labels, so I can give them the values of my domain objects, like

```
cell.myTestLabel.text = myDomainObject.sampleText;
```

The problem is, that I want to connect the button, so that the `MyViewController` can handle it and I can get the values of the table view row. How can I do this?

Does anyone know?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may setup the action handling manually, take a look on the message addTarget:action:forControlEvents: of your button

Answer (score 0):

You can create a handler in MyCell class and relate it with your button through XIB. This is the only solution.
You may additionally create a method in your ViewController class, which will be called from your button's event, from MyCell class.